# How to download Images without freeze or crash Delphi app

Tags: android, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I have this code. Make a `PHP Query` to server and the results are Image URLs.
I try to put them to a `Listbox`, in a `TImage` in `ListboxItems` with `AnonymousThread` and loop. All good on Windows but on Android the app crash.

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      aJSONArray: TJSOnArray;
      ThumbUrl, Postid: String;
      PCount: integer;
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Clear;
      Edit1.Text := '';

      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        begin
          aJSONArray := TJSOnArray.Create;
            aJSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.
              GetBytes(NetHTTPClient1.Get('https://server/getUserPhotos.php?userid=1').
              ContentAsString), 0) as TJSONArray;

            TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure
            var
              AI: Integer;
              LBI: TListBoxItem;
              img: TImage;
            begin
              ListBox1.ItemHeight := ((ListBox1.Width / 3)-2);
              ListBox1.ItemWidth := ((ListBox1.Width / 3)-2);
              for AI := 0 to (aJSONArray.Count -1) do
                begin
                  ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
                  ThumbUrl := (aJSonArray.Items[AI].GetValue<string>('image_url_150'));
                  Postid := (aJSonArray.Items[AI].GetValue<string>('post_id'));
                  if ThumbUrl <> '' then
                  begin
                    LBI := TListBoxItem.Create(Self);
                    LBI.Parent := ListBox1;
                    try
                      img := TImage.Create(self);
                      img.Parent := ListBox1.ItemByIndex(AI);
                      img.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
                      img.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.Fit;
                      with img.Margins do
                      begin
                        Left := 1;
                        Right := 1;
                        Top := 1;
                        Bottom := 1;
                      end;
                      img.Tag := StrToInt(Postid);
                      img.TagString := ThumbUrl;
                      img.OnPainting := imgPainting;
                    finally
                      ListBox1.EndUpdate;
                    end;
                  end;
                end;
            end);
            aJSONArray.Free;
        end).Start;
    end;

    procedure TForm10.imgPainting(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
      const ARect: TRectF);
    var
      AStream: TMemoryStream;
    begin

      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        begin
          try
            AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
            NetHTTPClient1.Get(TImage(Sender).TagString, AStream);
            AStream.Position := 0;

            TThread.Synchronize(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                TImage(Sender).Bitmap.LoadFromStream(AStream);
              end);
          finally
            AStream.Free;
          end;
        end).Start;
    end;
```

I try to download images in the loop but the app freezes until all images are downloaded. What goes wrong?

Comment: I don't think creating a thread in the `Painting` event is a good idea.

Comment: `aJSONArray` is set twice - whatever you `.Free()` later isn't what came from `.Create()`.

Comment: Your thread doing most of its work inside of `TThread.Synchronize()`, delegating the work back to the main UI thread, which defeats the whole purpose of using a thread. Also, why are you starting a thread in the `TImage.OnPaint` event? You should not be doing that at all.

Comment: You say the app is crashing.  Crashing HOW exactly?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Why are you download images in Image OnPainting event? Are you aware that OnPainting is called every time image needs to be redrawn? This means that you are downloading images for every repaint of your Image component. Instead you should download and load your images once at creation of your TImage component instead.

Comment: When i put this code in the `for..do` loop the downloading is perfect but while downloading the app is freezing                                                                               `HTTP.Get(ThumbUrl, AStream);
                    AStream.Position := 0;
                    img.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(AStream);`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau When i say it crashes I mean the app close and i must reopen it.

Comment: @PanMilkos the app will freeze during a download if you call `HTTP.Get()` in the main UI thread. Your `for..do` loop is running in the main UI thread due to it being inside `TThread.Synchronize()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I make these changes and it works fine.
First the `onPainting` procedure look like this to load the image when the `TImage` is on the screen, and second, no longer use the `TImage` this procedure.

```
procedure TForm10.imgPainting(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
var
AStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    NetHTTPClient1.Get(TImage(Sender).TagString, AStream);
    AStream.Position := 0;
    TImage(Sender).Bitmap.LoadFromStream(AStream);
  finally
    AStream.Free;
    TImage(Sender).OnPainting := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This will freese the app when the image download takes longer then normal... But if you use the thread bases `OnPainting` handler from your question, just remove the `OnPainting` event (like in the finally statement in this answer) BEFORE you start de download thread.